# In haskell, what exactly is the type of a constructor of an ADT that has no parameters?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I define a type

```
data A a = A a | B deriving Show
```

I know that `(B :: A Int) == (B :: A Double)` does not typecheck because `A Int` and `A Double` are different, unequal types, so I can't apply `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`

But then I can ask ghci what is `show B`, and ghci says it is the string "B". What exactly is the type of that `B`? Is it `A Int`? Why? And why does ghci not complain that the type of `B` is ambiguous, given that it can be `A a` for absolutely any `a`.

I can similarly ask ghci what is `show (B==B)`, and it says "True", what is the type of both those `B`'s?

When I ask ghci the type of B with `:t B`, it prints `B :: A a`, but unless I am confused in the two examples above it must be some *specific* type without any type parameters. So how do I find out what the type of `B` in `B==B` is?

I'm confused a little. Is this described anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour is an ghc extension that is called [ExtendedDefaultRules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).

Quoting from the link:

> However, it is tiresome for the user to have to specify the type, so
>   GHCi extends Haskell's type-defaulting rules (Section 4.3.4 of the
>   Haskell 2010 Report) as follows. The standard rules take each group of
>   constraints (C1 a, C2 a, ..., Cn a) for each type variable a, and
>   defaults the type variable if
>
> 1. The type variable a appears in no other constraints
> 2. All the classes Ci are standard.
> 3. At least one of the classes Ci is numeric.
>
> At the GHCi prompt, or with GHC if the -XExtendedDefaultRules flag is
>   given, the following additional differences apply:
>
> - Rule 2 above is relaxed thus: All of the classes Ci are
>     single-parameter type classes.
> - Rule 3 above is relaxed this: At least one of the classes Ci is
>     numeric, or is Show, Eq, or Ord.
>     The unit type () is added to the start of the standard list of types
>     which are tried when doing type defaulting.

So according to these rules, in `B == B` or `show B`, `()` is picked for `a`.

You can also test this by doing the following at the GHCi prompt:

```
:set -XNoExtendedDefaultRules
data Foo a = A a | B deriving Eq
B == B
```

which results in the expected `ambiguous type variable a` error.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted to know.